# Making android as a server?

Tags: android, webserver

I am using an android device as a web server. Everything works good in localhost, but i want it to be published. My device connects to internet through wifi, not 3G.
(device)--->(wifi router)--->(modem). I tried to foward the port but it didn't work. Seem like my device's ip was provided by the router, not the modem, therefore the modem cannot "see" it. Can you help me to do this? I want my server to be published.

Comment: You need to forward the port in the router.

Comment: How do You know port forwarding didn't work? Also, what IP addresses are on device, router, modem? Does Your provider assign You pulic IP? How are You testing Your setup?

Comment: i dont know whether my public IP is assigned by whom. But in my modem it said dynamic ip, dhcp enabled. In my router dynamic ip and dhcp enabled too. My modem ip is 192.168.1.X, my router is 192.168.0.X and all the device connect to the router will be assigned to 192:168.0.10X. I set up the NAT in my modem to forward to my android. But when accessing the public IP it just log me in the modem.

Comment: to Slaks: i tried in my router too but it said conflict. I think it conflict with the web management port of the router (port 80).